# How to insert point in mySQL table

Tags: mysql, geometry, point, mysql-spatial

I get an mySQL error saying 'ADDRESS_LONGI_LATIT_LOCATION' can not be null.
Likely that 'geomfromtext/pointfromtext' is returning a null. Whats wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO address (ADDRESS_NICKNAME,ADDRESS_LONGI_LATIT_LOCATION) 
VALUES ('Testing',geomfromtext('Point(10.20.45 34.23.79)'))
```

Another way

```
INSERT INTO address (ADDRESS_NICKNAME,ADDRESS_LONGI_LATIT_LOCATION) 
VALUES ('Testing',pointfromtext('10.20.45 34.23.79'))
```

Comment: Try to pay attention to the tags you put on your questions, as people are subscribed to them. If you don't put the right tags, your question gets less visibility and is less likely to be answered. In particular, you should always specify the technologies and frameworks you are using (like here, `mysql` and `mysql-spatial`). I just randomly came across your question because I was curious about what could a `point` question look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [specification of `ST_geomFromText()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext) (`geomfromtext()` is a deprecated synonym, you should not use it):

> If the geometry argument is `NULL` or not a syntactically well-formed geometry, or if the SRID argument is `NULL`, the return value is `NULL`.

Indeed your argument is not syntactically well-formed, as each coordinate contains two dots. You can check this with a simple:

```
select geomfromtext('Point(10.20.45 34.23.79)')
```

Result ([try online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/57380)):

> (null)

With a single dot, it works:

```
select geomfromtext('Point(10.2045 34.2379)')
```

Result ([true online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/57382))

> AAAAAAEBAAAAYhBYObRoJED129eBcx5BQA==

The same applies to [`ST_PointFromText(()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-pointfromtext), except you still need to use [the WKT format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkt-format) so you need to use `POINT()` as well:

```
select pointfromtext('point(10.2045 34.2379)')
```

Result ([try online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/57386)):

> AAAAAAEBAAAAYhBYObRoJED129eBcx5BQA==

Basically the two functions are the same, except `pointfromtext()` enforces a point result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not notice that at all. It's working now.